# Enquiry about Basic C++ Regarding Structs

Tags: c++, struct

I am creating a basic C++ code for my first school assignment that simply requires me to create a program that asks for a time in hours, minutes and seconds and converts how much time this is equivalent to in seconds; extremely basic.

I think the errors I am getting are because of my possible misuse of the struct function.

After getting the same error: "expected primary-expression before â.â token" after multiple trials of tweaks, I decided to try the code without struct; simply defining them with float h,m,s,et and calling them by that name: cin >> h >> m >> s;. And it works. This is why I think the error is with my use of the struct function.

Here is the short code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

struct time {
 int hour;
 int minute;
 int second;
 int elapsedTime;
};

cout << "Enter a Time in the Format: HH MM SS: ";

cin >> time.hour >> time.minute >> time.second;

time.elapsedTime = ((time.hour*360)+(time.minute*60)+time.second);

cout << "The Amount of Time Elasped is: " << time.elapsedTime << " seconds." << endl;

return 0;

}
```

The aforementioned error is in the code's 16th line 3 times and once in it's 20th line.

Another error in the 18th line is: "expected unqualified-id before â.â token".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I refuse to look at the professor's posted answers yet.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: In C++ you should use classes instead of structs. Anyway, which is 18th line?

Comment: You're confusing type definitions with variable declarations. You need both. You need a type like your time struct, then you need to create a variable of that type.

Comment: @m0skit0: why? you sure can use structs, in C++ they're basically classes with all members `public`.

Comment: Just a little (unrelated) tip: When posting questions about errors, you should put the complete error message(s) in the question, unedited. Also mark the the lines in whatever source you provide, it can be hard to count lines sometimes, especially if you should post large snippets of code (which is discouraged anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
struct time {
 int hour;
 int minute;
 int second;
 int elapsedTime;
};
```

you just *declared* the structure of your struct. You have to *instantiate* an instance of it:

```
time mytime;
cin >> mytime.hour;
cin >> mytime.minute;
cin >> mytime.second;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Constantinius. I had tried to instantiate but the bigger mistake was the 16th line with cin >> somethign >> something else. they should be on different lines.

it works and i understand c++ a lot better thanks to your specification :)



Edit: the reason I use struct and not class is because it's a strict requirement of the assignment. we haven't learned class yet. lol

Comment: Isn't the variable declaration `struct time mytime`?

Comment: @m0skit0: No, in C++ that's not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a struct for this; just get the three components of the time in separate variables and do a little arithmetic. But if you **really** want to use a struct, keep in mind that the definition of a struct creates a new type. That part of your code is fine. Once you've done that, you need to create a variable of that type:

```
time data;
```

and then you can access the fields, as `data.hour`, `data.minute`, `data.second`.

Answer (score 0):

`struct time` is a data type. What you need is a variable of that type:

```
struct time t;

cin >> t.hour >> t.minute >> t.second;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 3600 seconds in one hour by the way